# Parenthesis in MySQL Regex queries with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, regex, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a python application which searches a database using SQLAlchemy like so:

```
query = raw_input('Search: ')
db.session.query(Posts).filter(Posts.name.op('REGEXP')(r'[[:<:]]{}'.format(query))).all()
```

This works fine with my MySQL database with most characters however I have found some searches do not work.

- Searches that include `(` without a `)` following it somewhere after return an error
- Searches that contain foreign characters like `Б`, `э`, `д` or `ц` also returns an error

Is there a solution to support ALL kinds of search queries including special and foreign characters? Thanks.

Comment: Please find out the resulting SQL; who knows what SqlAlchemy is doing.

Answer (score 0):

> Searches that include ( without a ) following it somewhere after return an error

This is happening since `(` and `)` have special meaning in regular expressions. The expression would not be valid, if, for example, there is an opening parenthesis without a closing one:

```
>>> re.compile(r"test (")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

You need to *[escape](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) the query*:

```
import re

query = re.escape(query)
```

Comment: I tried this method, while this works, the method `.escape()` seems to just add a backslash to the parenthesis so I search the database for something, it searches for `\(` not `(`.